# Alternate background color of row in recycle-adapter whiteout break the animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I want to have `RecyclerView` with alternate color and when I click on each row I have a tape animation.

Now the tape animation work. But when I want to add the code to change color my click animation doesn't work anymore.

Here is my row code :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"//Here is where my tap animation is set>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@android:dimen/app_icon_size" tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            android:id="@+id/contactImg"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    />
    <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/titleView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/subTitleView" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/contactImg" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/subTitleView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/contactImg"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is my alternate color code in my recycler adapter class :

```java
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHoler holder, int position) {
        holder.titleView.setText(ContactList.get(position));
        holder.subTitleView.setText(String.valueOf(position));
        if (position%2==1){ //check if the position of row is odd
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(appResources.getColor(R.color.lightDark)); //if is odd I apply one color
        }else{
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);//if isn't odd I aply another color
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be because you are setting background with animation and color at same time. By your setBackgroundColor method in onBindViewHolder method you are replacing the animation with your color. 
Remove `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`
 and do whatever you want to set inside the onBindViewHolder method.

Comment: yes but how I can add the selectable item background from code ?

Comment: You need to set the animation onClick event of list item. try removing the backgroundAnimation from layout and set it programmatically on listItemClick()